# php cron jobs working fine on cPanel server but giving errors on non cPanel server

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have 2 server one is with cPanel and other is without cPanel

i am running same php scripts as cron jobs on both servers.

All scripts are running fine on cPanel server but on non-cPanel server i am getting `file not found error`

`Failed opening required '../includes/config.php'`

i have 15+ cron job php scripts.

is there any way to **fix this without editing all my php scripts and adding __FILE__** on all includes and required?

how all these scripts running fine on cPanel without __FILE__?

Comment: 15 scripts isn't a big deal. I had to edit 150 once, I said "once". Always use a full system path for worse case scenarios.

Comment: Edit 150 fiels for add a line its a little script for 10 seconds.;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cron may need to run the script from the directory it's in. You could update the crontab to `cd` to the script directory, then execute it, like so (example):

`0 12 * * * cd /path/to/your/script/ ; php your_script.php > /dev/null 2>&1`